# Create a table with PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that rotates a stock prices table, but it uses a temp table.

I would like to know how to store this rotated table in a table.
I have struggled to use this query with 'create table' because there is some variables declarations.

Here is the code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TEMP','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMP;
DECLARE @COL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @HEADER NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @FIX NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @VAR NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ORDER NVARCHAR(MAX);
WITH
#TEMP AS(
select Cast(MarketDate as Date) as date_, oo.seccode, ConstFlag  
FROM 
(select distinct seccode, InfoCode, MarketDate, Constflag
from ds_russell1000_prices_adj_r) oo
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM #TEMP
SET @FIX = 'Date_';
SET @VAR = 'Constflag'
SET @HEADER = 'seccode';
SELECT @COL = COALESCE(@COL + ',','') + QUOTENAME(seccode) FROM #TEMP F
GROUP BY QUOTENAME(seccode)
ORDER BY QUOTENAME(seccode)
SET @ORDER = 'Date_'
SET @SQL = 'SELECT  ' + @FIX + ',' + @COL + ' FROM (SELECT ' + @FIX + ',' +
VAR + ', ' + @HEADER + ' FROM #TEMP) P
PIVOT (sum(' + @VAR + ') FOR ' + @HEADER + ' in (' + @COL + ')) PVT
ORDER BY ' + @ORDER + ''
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

IF OBJECT_ID('ds_russell1000_positions_ROTATED') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE
ds_russell1000_positions_ROTATED;
select * into ds_russell1000_positions_ROTATED
from #TEMP
```

Could someone help please?

Comment: Can you achieve your goal for a given special case, where all variables can be replaced by examples of constant values? I.e. can you narrow the problem down to variables by making your code work without variables?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line:

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
```

Simply replace `#TEMP` with the name of the permanent table you wish to create.

Also take the `#` sign off the name of your CTE:

```
WITH
TEMP AS(
...
FROM TEMP
```

`#` signs are for naming temporary tables and should not be used in other object names.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your help, but its still not working. It gives me this error message "Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Invalid object name '#TEMP'."